# Error with installing apache-beam[gcp] on mac zsh terminal - “zsh: no matches found: apache-beam[gcp]”

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using zsh, and I have installed gcloud in order to interact with GCP via local terminal on my Mac. I am encountering this error *“zsh: no matches found: apache-beam[gcp]”.* However, when I run the command directly on the bash terminal on the GCP console, there was no such error. How do I deal? Thank you.

Comment: I found the answer. According to this reddit post https://www.reddit.com/r/googlecloud/comments/dve3ie/python_apachebeam_library/, the user BBHoss, who said You're using zsh, so you need to put the package name in quotes.” 

pip install 'apache-beam[gcp]' actually works.

Comment: You should turn this comment into an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 34):

```
pip install "apache-beam[gcp]"
```

^ This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

As Navaneeth Pk suggested, enclose your library name in double quotes, eg pip install "apache-beam[gcp]"